# On a subset sum version.

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

In subset sum we ask 'Given $n$ numbers in $\Bbb Z$, is there a subset of them that sums to $0$?' this is $NP$ complete.

Consider variant:

'Given $n$ of degree at most $d$ polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ with coefficients in $\{0,1\}$ is there a subset of them that sums to $x^{d-1}+x^{d-2}+\dots+1$?'

Is this $NP$ complete? Is there any approximation algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand the approximation part of the question.  What would you be approximating?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe is equivalent to the [EXACT COVER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem, which is known to be NP-complete.

The EXACT COVER problem definition from Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, given a collection $S$ of subsets of a set $X$, an exact cover is a subcollection $S^*$ of $S$ such that each element in $X$ is contained in exactly one subset in $S^*$.

EXACT COVER reduces to your problem as follows:

Set $d$ equal to $|X|$.  For each element in $X$ map a unique power of $x$ to it, always less than $d$.  For each subset of $X$ in $S$ build a polynomial by replacing the set elements with their mappings to powers of $x$ and adding plus signs between them.

Now, any solution to your problem i.e. a set of polynomials that sums to $x^{d-1}+x^{d-2}+\dots+1$ is also a solution to the reduced EXACT COVER problem.  The EXACT COVER solution, $S^*$, can be recovered by reversing the set element mappings in the solution polynomials and removing the plus signs.

Comment: I've provided the reduction.

Comment: like approximately summing in some norm?